# How to map two arrays and output data for matching parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following two arrays:

```
const dates = [  "January 1st, 2022", "January 2nd, 2022", More dates...]
const events = [
{
  id: 1,
  date: "January 10th, 2022",
  title: "Have a meeting",
}
More events...
]
```

What I would like to do is map through the dates array, displaying all dates and also map through the events array and display the event.title when the event.date matches the corresponding date in the date array.. How can I map the events array with the dates array and when the dates match output the event.title?

Currently I have this:

```
 {dates.map((date, i) => (
      <li
        key={i}
       >
        {date}
       //Here I would also like to display the {event.title} when the dates match.
      </li>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(with Optional chaining operator (?.))

```
{dates.map((date, i) => (
          <li
            key={i}
           >
    {events.find(e => e.date == date)?.title}
          </li>
      ))}
```

Comment: Thanks @Okan, that worked a treat, I just had to edit the optional chaining to a ternary statement to include an else statement, so `? event.title :  "" `. This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If all your dates are strings and they match the strings in the `dates` array, then you could structure your events as an object where the keys are the dates. (This is assuming there are no overlapping events).

The benefit of this method is that it you only have two loops which makes the code very performant.

```
const structuredEvents = events.reduce((acc, cur => {
  acc[cur.date] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

In your loop select the event based on the `date`.

```
{dates.map((date, i) => {
  const event = structuredEvents[date];

  return (
    <li
      key={i}
    >
      {date}
      {event?.title}
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Hi @Emiel, thanks for the response, it's a great answer! So basically as I map through the dates it would output the event title if there is one for the current date?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const dates = [  "January 1st, 2022", "January 2nd, 2022", ]
const events = [
{
  id: 1,
  date: "January 1st, 2022",
  title: "Have a meeting",
},
{
  id: 1,
  date: "January 2nd, 2022",
  title: "second meeting",
},
{
  id: 1,
  date: "January 3rd, 2022",
  title: "Have a meeting",
}
]

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
{dates.map((date, i) => (
      <li
        key={i}
       >
        {events.map((data,i)=> {
          console.log(data,date,"data...")
          return (
          <div>
            {data.date == date ? 
       <div>Here I would also like to display the {data.title} when the dates match.</div>
       :null}
          </div>
        )})}
      </li>
  ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding the logic here to get the filtered array which contains only title based on the comparison we made in `dates` & `events` array.

```js
const dates = ["January 1st, 2022", "January 2nd, 2022"];

const events = [{
  id: 1,
  date: "January 1st, 2022",
  title: "Have a meeting 1st January",
}, {
  id: 2,
  date: "January 10th, 2022",
  title: "Have a meeting 10th January",
}, {
  id: 2,
  date: "January 2nd, 2022",
  title: "Have a meeting 2nd January",
}];

const res = events.filter((obj) => dates.includes(obj.date)).map((obj) => `${obj.date} - ${obj.title}`);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This only returns an array with the matching event titles though, what I am after is displaying the date and the corresponding event title.

Comment: @adherb I improved the answer as per your comment. Kindly check. Hope it will work as per your requirement.